# Modal inside an inactive tab on Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, modal-dialog

My app's simplified structure looks like this:

- tab 1

  - modal
  - button
- tab 2

  - diagram

The button opens a modal, and that part works fine. What I need to add is when the users drops an element on the diagram, the same modal should be shown. But since tab1 is not active at that time, the modal is invisible.

Is there a way to show the modal without activating the tab that contains it?

**EDIT**: I cannot move the modal outside of tabs, because it's quite a complicated structure, generated dynamically and each tab comes as a "package" of list, buttons, modals and other stuff...

Comment: hi! I'm facing the same problem. How did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In the [bootstrap api](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) says that you could show a modal using the following:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')                // initializes and invokes show immediately
```

Comment: That works when I'm on tab1, but when I'm on tab2, showing the modal is not effective, because it's container is invisible.

Comment: So, you could move the tab you like
$('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show') // Select tab by name
and then show the modal.